# Kofax transformation - Update fields on form on validation

Tags: vba, kofax

I use Kofax Transform to extract data from OCR. 
For this i have a form with several inputs. Basically : name, surname, email.
My issue concerns the validation step.

I want to update the input fields on specific event (click on enter when the email field is selected and update the values from a database). On this database table I have 4 fields : id, name, surname and email

It's my first VBA expertience and I have to create a script:

```
Private Sub FillFormOneEmailValidated(ByVal pXDoc As CASCADELib.CscXDocument)

   'define required properties
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

   Dim sqlRequest As String
   Dim email As String

   Dim dbHostServer As String
   Dim dbUsername As String
   Dim dbPassword As String
   Dim dbName As String
   Dim dbConnString As String

   'Prapare the db connection
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset  : Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

   dbHostServer = "127.0.0.1"
   dbUsername = "root"
   dbPassword = "root"
   dbName = "dbtest"

   'build the connection string and open connection to database
   dbConnString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};
   dbConnString = dbConnString & "Server=" & dbHostServer & ";"
   dbConnString = dbConnString & "UID=" & dbUsername & ";"
   dbConnString = dbConnString & "PWD=" & dbPassword & ";"
   dbConnString = dbConnString & "database=" & dbName

   'Create recordset and set conncetion
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset : : Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   cn.ConnectionString = dbConnString
   cn.Open

   'build query
   sqlRequest = "SELECT name, surname, email FROM users WHERE email = " & email 
   Set rs = cn.Execute(sqlRequest)

   'iterate the values of the sql request
   On Error Resume Next
   rs.MoveFirst
     pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("name") = CStr(sqlRequest("name"))

   rs.Close : Set rs = Nothing
   cn.Close : Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here are my issues :

- it seems that this code is not correct.
- How can i "observe" an event on the email input (form) in KTA Transform ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid building sql query like that since its a potential injection risk. Look into using parameters.  (Or hope nobody's kid is named bobby drop table, or be subject to a malicious user)

Also passwords in scripts are not recommended.

2. I'd look into the already built in functionalities of The database locator. And database dialog you can add to your validation mask.
3. If script is the only possible thing

You can use multiple events to to this. One way as you said is when the field is confirmed ValidationForm_AfterTableCellChanged.

You can see events available to you in the Project builder/Script editor by the dropdown options
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ADKf.png)

Not sure for KTA, but in normal KT you can debug and observe other how methods are doing by enabling the Script debugging in the synchronization options.

4. The error in the script looks obvious

sqlRequest is your query as String variable. You must get your row data from the recordset. (i have not checked the rest of the script)